# how to pass java objects as parameters in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a function to insert data into about 20 tables which have dependencies. The front end team has given reference object to be passed into the procedure.Can I pass these objects as such in procedure. If so how can I extract values from those inside procedure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Rose

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass objects to the procedure but yes you can iterate over of the objects and pass the values within the procedure. Databases know the tables only, they are in no way concerned with OBJECTS of the application layer.

Comment: Then how can I take the objects inside the procedure to iterate. Pardon me if this is a stupid question. But I dont have any idea on this.

The scenario is when a mew form is created it should be saved in DB. There are around 20 tables to be inserted with data and you have dependencies among tables.
How to get values inside the procedure if I cannot pass objects

Comment: can you modify the procedure to accept the values..e.g. if your object has 2 string.. procedure can be like  myproc(string1,string2) ??

Comment: Yes.. but They have given 8 objects for complete insertion. kindly let me know how I can move forward

Comment: are you using any orm?

Comment: sorry what is orm?. They have given me 8 object and JSON strucure

Comment: object relational mapping

Comment: No They didnt give any ORM.